# repeating values in a string

Tags: bash, snmp

I have a bash shell that is pulling down values for memory to tell me if they are OK or not. It will return 03 if the memory is good. In the system memory amounts could vary but say in one I have a bank of 12 modules. SNMP would return as a single string:

03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03

03 means it is OK. Anything other than 03 is a problem. Is there a simple way in bash to parse thru what I would guess is a space separated list and if any contain anything other than 03 return an error or return OK?

Thanks.

JR

Answer (score 0):

iVal=`grep "03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03" fileName`

if iVal=0 you have a mach.  If not, you do not have a match.

note that those are grave accents (back tick)  before grep and at the end of the line.

try `man grep` and `man bash`

if you want something more configurable (different length response) you can use regex to be more generic or you can use `awk` to parse a certain length of string (or number of variables)

Comment: `iVal` doesn't contain the exit status if you combine it with command substitution, it contains the actual output of the command.

Comment: This would work with `if [[ -n "$iVal" ]]` to check for failure or `if [[ -z "$iVal" ]]` to check for success.  Or use "grep -c" and integer compare the output for being greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with `awk`:

```
 awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!="03") print "fail"}' <yourfile>
```

Or something similar. Essentially that will loop through every field in your record (a field being one of your numbers in the record), check it to see if it's "03" and if not, then print "fail".

Answer (score 0):

If the values are whitespace-separated like your example, the default `$IFS` value will split the string up for you.  So, you could do something like this:

```
status_string=$(snmpwalk arg arg arg)
ok=1
for status in $status_string
do
  [[ "${status:-}" != "03" ]] && ok=0
done
```

If the data is in a file, you can just use `$(</path/to/file)` to get the file contents into memory.  This will work if values are newline-separated, space-separated, or tab-separated.  Or some combination of those chars.

The `"${var:-}"` expression will return an empty string if `$var` is empty or undefined, preventing the script from complaining about empty vars.  I recommend that structure any time a variable could be empty (assuming a shell which supports that, which should be any common bourne-style shell).

Comment: Probably should clarify a couple things.  When I mention Memory, I'm referring to SNMP call that is querying the memory to see if it has any failure.   So there is no physical file I'm reading from.  I'm doing an SNMP call: result=$(snmpwalk -Oqv -v2c -c public $1 ${!calculatedvariables[count]}) storing that in result and then trying to parse whatever is in there to make sure it's all 03 space 03 space 03 space... values or if there are any other values.

Comment: When I mention getting a value into memory, I mean into a variable. :)  Stick your `snmpwalk` command where I have `snmpget or whatever`, replace the exit with return, and wrap the code in something like `function checkmemory {}`.  If I'm making too many assumptions about how easy this would be to do, add another comment saying as much and I'll expand the example to something more complete.

Comment: I simplified the example a bit to maybe make it more useful.

Comment: Nicely done.  Can't vote it or accept as answer but thanks dannysauer.